# How to exclude some fields from being copied to realm database?

Tags: android, realm

I want to exclude some fields that are not supported by realm such as Calendar. Let us suppose I have this class.

```
class time extends RealmObject{

private Calendar calendar;
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private int hour;
private int minute
//... getters and setters
}
```

How can I exclude Calendar since it is not supported by realm. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I think there is [`@Ignore` annotation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/Ignore.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [@Ignore annotation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/Ignore.html)  on your field.

```
class time extends RealmObject{
    @Ignore
    private Calendar calendar;
```